# Alguien sabe como pasar los datos de un input de una pagina a otra pero de forma local?

Tags: javascript, html, css

El tema es que me pidieron para un trabajo un formulario que se completa y que cuando toque el boton enviar me rediriga a  otra pagina y que los datos que cargue en el formulario anterior este cargado en esa pagina nueva en un nuevo div con los datos del formulario anterior.No estoy logrando conseguir por localstorege '

Comment: Hola, Álvaro. Por favor, edita tu publicación y muéstranos la parte crítica del código que, según leo en tu descripción, no te está funcionando. Así podremos ayudarte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar [*localstorage*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) para almacenar un dato que luego puedas recuperar, en el cliente.

He preparado un ejemplo que he dejado en los siguientes *snippets*, aunque el sandbox de StackOverflow no permite el acceso a *localstorage* y por tanto, no podrás verlos en funcionamiento aquí, pero puedes alojarlos en cualquier sitio y debieran funcionar.

La mecánica es: Entras a la primera página, escribes un nombre y le das clic en  el botón *Guardar*.

Luego entras a la segunda página y debiera mostrarte el nombre que guardaste en la primera ya cargado en el *input* correspondiente.

Primera página:

```js
function guardarNombre() {
  iNombre = document.getElementById("nombre");
  nombre = iNombre.value;
  localStorage.setItem("nombre", nombre);
}
```

```html
<label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
<input id="nombre" type="text" placeholder="tu nombre" />
<button onClick="guardarNombre()">Guardar</button>
```

Segunda página:

```js
function leerNombre() {
  const nombre = localStorage.getItem("nombre");
  console.log(nombre);
  iNombre = document.getElementById("nombre");
  iNombre.value = nombre;
}

leerNombre();
```

```html
<label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
<input id="nombre" type="text" placeholder="tu nombre" />
```